# Is a factory reset of a modern Windows install using the cloud installation option equivalent to a clean install using a physical install media?

Tags: windows, system-restore

Modern Windows versions (10 and 11) have a recovery feature to perform a factory reset where the new version of Windows is downloaded from the cloud. I was wondering if this feature is equivalent to the classic method of doing this through a physical install media like a boot disk or USB drive in that it can be used to nuke a problematic machine and bring it to a known and verified good state, regardless of whether the problems were caused by data corruption or malware, a state which can then be used to enable Windows security features which require a fresh install like the new installation verification system.

Comment: All methods that result in the installation or upgrade of Windows use the same process.  The only difference between a clean install and an upgrade install is if the user profiles are transferred to the new installation.  If you have concerns you are infected with malware you should be deleting all partitions on your disk and then installing Windows.

Comment: If you don't trust the machine then you shouldn't be trusting it to download or not tamper with a clean install image before installing. You should download the image and write it to a USB on a trusted machine and then wipe everything as mentioned by Ramhound.

Comment: While the methods are the same, one of the reasons "Fresh Start" exists, is that Microsoft wanted to offer users a method to install a version of Windows without OEM software installed.  OEM software is often the cause of performance problems. Due to many legacy reasons, Microsoft can't prevent OEMs from providing this software with their software in their preinstalled images on their own hardware.

Comment: @JW0914 - Upgrade 1507 to 1903 and you will find that Windows.old is used. Then perform the same operation with 1507 but perform a clean install, you will again have a Windows.old, the difference will be one will transfer the user profiles the other will not.  My statement is factual true. If you perform a “clean install” from within Windows partitions absolutely are not deleted. I can bring out a diagram from Microsoft that proves what I say, I have done it before, I know I am absolutely 100% correct. QED

Comment: @JW0914 - I cannot delete commentary unless it’s my own.

Comment: @JW0914 Ramhound does not have the Moderator diamond behind their name, so he isn't a moderator and hence can't delete comments of other users. Also, if you have problems with the moderation, there are better avenues to extoll them than the comment section of an entirely unrelated question, especially when those comments send notifications to the person asking that question.